# Quartz tables to be used

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have configured a quartz jdbc store and got the cron job scheduled & running in my spring boot app. However, I would like to understand if it is necessary to use all the tables mentioned in the quartz distribution?

There are about 9-10 tables and I don't see all or most of it getting values after the job execution. When are they actually used? Hence, is it actually necessary to maintain all the tables suggested by quartz?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, they are all needed. You may configure a table prefix name. But anyway, they all make part of Quartz runtime, do not touch them.

Comment: Thank you @PeterMmm for confirming this.

Comment: This answer could be more helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557255/what-does-each-table-for-quartz-scheduler-signify